# How to add annotation over line plot to mark percent change in y-values between discrete x-values

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, emmeans

I want to visualize the results of a linear model where dependent variable values change as a function of discrete x-values. Since my x-values represent consecutive days, I want to annotate the change from day to day, in percents. How can I do this in a line plot?

## My Data

I want to measure people's mood. Every day I collect responses from 1000 different people on how they feel. I therefore get a daily average for mood, and I want to see how it changes from one day to another.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(emmeans)

day_1 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 77, sd = 18)
day_2 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 74, sd = 19)
day_3 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 80, sd = 5)
day_4 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 76, sd = 18)


df <- 
  cbind(day_1, day_2, day_3, day_4) %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  gather(., key = day, value = mood, day_1:day_4) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(day), factor)

> df

## # A tibble: 4,000 x 2
##   day    mood
##    <fct> <dbl>
##  1 day_1  83.9
##  2 day_1  94.9
##  3 day_1 104. 
##  4 day_1  81.0
##  5 day_1  61.4
##  6 day_1  95.1
##  7 day_1  78.6
##  8 day_1 108. 
##  9 day_1  74.7
## 10 day_1  79.7
## # ... with 3,990 more rows
```

### Fitting and plotting

```r
fit <-  lm(formula = mood ~ day, data = df)

emmip(fit, ~ day, CIs = TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

---

- **Given that the plot object can be edited using ggplot functions, how can I add the change between days, in percents, such as the following illustration?**
- Is there an efficient way to calculate the change and put it above each section of the line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach utilizes `ggplot_build()` (included from `ggplot2` itself) to pull out the underlying data used to create your plot, then `geom_label()` to perform the annotation itself.

#### Preparations

As indicated, we can use `ggplot_build()` to pull the data from your dataset.

```
p <- emmip(fit, ~ day, CIs = TRUE)  # save your plot as gg object
plotdata <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
```

There's kind of a lot going on there in the `ggplot_build()` function, so I'll explain.  We want to access the `data` part of the result, and when you do that you get the datasets used to create each of the layers.  In the plot, you have 3 layers: the points, the lines, and the bars for the CI.  In principle, you can pull any of those, but I'm choosing the first one (`[[1]]`).  In particular, we want to access the `y` values.

To calculate the percent change, I have written a small function to do this for us that uses `diff()`.  Since `diff()` does not return a "0" for the first index, we have to add that.  Then we add the column to `plotdata`:

```
percent_change <- function(x) {
  p_change <- (diff(x)/x[1:length(x)-1])*100
  return(c(0,p_change))  # add back the 0 for the first index
}

plotdata$change <- percent_change(plotdata$y)
```

#### Plotting

Now we're ready for the plot.  We'll add a label geom to the plot, `p`.  There's a few things going on in there:

- Filtering to use only the `plotdata` parts where `plotdata$change != 0`.  This is because we don't want to label any points where there is no change (i.e. the first point).
- I need to add a "+" preceding positive values of `plotdata$change`.  `ifelse()` within the label aesthetic seems to work just fine.
- color can be dynamically changed here.  You could also map it via `aes()`, but I would need to create another column and so it's just convenient here to use `ifelse()` to control the color as red or green, since there's only two options.  You have to do this outside of the `aes()`, otherwise you will only get a legend and default `ggplot2` colors for the labels "red" and "green".  No legend is created the way I do it here.

Code and plot here:

```
p + geom_label(
  data=subset(plotdata, change != 0),
  aes(x=x, y=y,
    label=paste0(ifelse(
      subset(plotdata, change!=0)$change <0, '','+'),
      round(change, 2),'%')),
  color=ifelse(subset(plotdata, change!=0)$change <0, 'red','green3'),
  nudge_x = -0.3
)
```

[image]