# Scatterpie: How to add annotation over line connecting pies to mark percent change in y-values between pies

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I have a scatterpie plot with pies plotted over x and y axes and a "trend line" connecting them. In the spirit of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63054052/6105259), I would like to add an annotation over each line to mark the percent increase/decrease between the y-values underlying each adjacent pies.

### My data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scatterpie)

my_df <- structure(list(day_in_july = 13:20, yes_and_yes = c(0.611814345991561, 
0.574750830564784, 0.593323216995448, 0.610539845758355, 0.650602409638554, 
0.57429718875502, 0.575971731448763, 0.545454545454545), yes_but_no = c(0.388185654008439, 
0.425249169435216, 0.406676783004552, 0.389460154241645, 0.349397590361446, 
0.42570281124498, 0.424028268551237, 0.454545454545455), y = c(0.388185654008439, 
0.425249169435216, 0.406676783004552, 0.389460154241645, 0.349397590361446, 
0.42570281124498, 0.424028268551237, 0.454545454545455)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### My current visualization

```r
p <- ggplot(data = my_df) +
  geom_path(aes(x=day_in_july, y = y*50)) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y*50, r = 0.3), 
                  data = my_df, 
                  cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3],
                  color = "red") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = y*50, x = day_in_july, 
                label = paste0(formatC(y*100, digits = 3), "%")),
            nudge_y = 0.07, nudge_x = -0.25, size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(y = y*50, x = day_in_july, 
            label = paste0(formatC((1-y)*100, digits = 3), "%")),
            nudge_y = -0.07, nudge_x = 0.25, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "seagreen3")) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = xvals, breaks = xvals) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "yes but no",
                     labels = function(x) x/50) + 
  coord_fixed()

> p
```

[image: scatterpie]

### I want to add percent increase/decrease between y-values of adjacent pies

The y-value of the first pie (at `day_in_july` = `13`) is `0.388`. From this y-value to the next pie's y-value (`0.425`) there's a percent increase of 9.53%. Therefore, I want to mark the line that connects the two pies with a label of **+9.53%** .

### Ultimately, I want the plot to look like this one:

[image: sp_w_line_annotated]

### On the way to the solution

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63054052/6105259) already has the relevant mechanism to get what I'm looking for.
The idea is to use `ggplot_build()` to access the data underlying the plot, then calculate the percent change between two consecutive values, then rebuild the plot with the lines annotated accordingly. However, this solution isn't working for me with the scatterpie plot since the underlying data outputted from `ggplot_build` is of its own kind.

```r
plot_data <- ggplot_build(p) %>% ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] %>% as.tibble()

> plot_data

## # A tibble: 2,904 x 13
##    fill  group   index amount PANEL stringsAsFactors nControl     x     y colour  size linetype alpha
##    <chr> <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct> <lgl>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>
##  1 pink  1     0        0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13    19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  2 pink  1     0.00452  0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  3 pink  1     0.00905  0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  4 pink  1     0.0136   0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  5 pink  1     0.0181   0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  6 pink  1     0.0226   0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  7 pink  1     0.0271   0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  8 pink  1     0.0317   0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
##  9 pink  1     0.0362   0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
## 10 pink  1     0.0407   0.612 1     FALSE                 221  13.0  19.7 red      0.5        1 NA   
## # ... with 2,894 more rows
```

Where are the actual y-values that I need for calculating the percent change between pies' y-values? Obviously, I can get the y-values from the data. But in order to reconstruct the plot, this data from `ggplot_build()` doesn't make sense to me, and I don't know how to utilize the technique to add the percentage change between pies to the plot line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt with the ggrepel package. I basically created a new data frame containing necessary information for `geom_label_repel()`. I omit the details of what I did to create `foo`. But I think you can read it. I invested a bit of time to find the optimal positions for the label, and this is what I could do for you for now. If you are not happy with the position, you gotta play around by yourself.

```
foo <- tibble(day_in_july = my_df$day_in_july + 0.5,
              y = my_df$y * 50 + (((lead(my_df$y * 50) - (my_df$y * 50))) / 2),
              gap = ((lead(my_df$yes_but_no) / my_df$yes_but_no) - 1) * 100) %>% 
       mutate(gap = paste(round(gap, digits = 2), "%", sep = ""),
              hue = ifelse(gap > 0, "green", "red"))


p <- ggplot(data = my_df) +
     geom_path(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y*50)) +
     geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y*50, r = 0.3), 
                     data = my_df, 
                     cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3],
                     color = "red") + 
     geom_text(aes(y = y * 50, x = day_in_july, 
               label = paste0(formatC(y * 100, digits = 3), "%")),
               nudge_y = 0.07, nudge_x = -0.25, size = 3) +
     geom_text(aes(y = y * 50, x = day_in_july, 
               label = paste0(formatC((1-y) * 100, digits = 3), "%")),
               nudge_y = -0.07, nudge_x = 0.25, size = 3) +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "seagreen3")) +
     geom_label_repel(data = foo, 
                      aes(x = day_in_july, y = y, 
                      color = hue, label = as.character(gap)),
                      show.legend = FALSE,
                      nudge_x = 0.3,
                      direction = "y",
                      vjust = -1.0) +
     scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! By the way, I added `coord_fixed()` to  your solution to make the pies completely round.

Comment: @akrun It has been at least three months since I answered SO questions. I have been teaching online. Now it is the end of the semester. I still need to provide final exams and mark them. How have you been doing? It'd be great to chat and catch up when you have time.

Comment: @Emman I am glad that the solution is working for you!

Comment: @jazzurro Sure, life is going on.  Nothing much happening on my side.